# Using SQLAlchemy, Accessing Latest Value for Foreign Key as Attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm sure I'm wording this improperly, mainly because I'm not quite sure how I'm looking to achieve my goal here...

I've got an SQL Alchemy db class that, among other things, stores a value for the price of a commodity. I need to do two things with this price:

1. Access the latest `price` of a `Commodity` at any given moment
2. Access historical `Commodity.price` changes

Currently, my models look like this:

```
class Commodity(Base):

    # Create Tablename
    __tablename__ = "commodities"

    # Defaults
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    updated = Column(DateTime, onupdate=datetime.now)

    # Uniques
    name = Column(String(), unique=True)
    price = ???

class Price(Base):

    # Create Tablename
    __tablename__ = "prices"

    # Defaults
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    # Uniques
    date = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.now)
    commodity = Column(ForeignKey(Commodity))
    price = Column(Integer())
```

In the `Commodity` class you'll note I have a `???` value as a placeholder for the price. I'd like to be able to access the price as `Commodity.price` in a way that would give me the latest value for that `Commodity`, identical to the following query:

`Price.query.order_by('updated desc').limit(1)`

I'm very new to SQL Alchemy, and appreciate that my approach may be wrong in general. Any help would be much-appreciated.

With my current understanding, I am planning to create an entry in the `prices` table for each update and simply update the `Commodity.price` value during the process. It seems a bit more elegant to use a function to get the `Commodity.price` via the `prices` table though. Is such an approach possible/recommended?

EDIT 1:
Essentially, I'm wondering how to do something like this:

```
class Commodity(Base):
    ...
    price = Column(ForeignKey(Price.query.order_by('updated desc').limit(1)))
```

Just to clarify, this isn't (to my understanding) a one-to-many relationship but, rather, a many-to-many.

Comment: Read sqlalchemy docs about foreign key relationships. That's where your solution is. If you still not able to solve this reply below I will post the solution :)

Comment: Maybe you could at least give me a hint as to which section it would be in?

Comment: Related docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html
Yours is one to many relationships as a commodity can have 1 price but 1 price can relate to multiple commodities. Give the docs a read and reply here if you still have doubts, I will answer.

Comment: I get that, but I'm confused as to how I'd implement the `Commodity.price` approach of accessing data. Should it just be assumed that I'll have to update the value of `Commodity.price` for every new entry into the `prices` table that is for a particular `Commodity`? That's the approach that makes sense to me, though I thought there might be a more dynamic way to do it. See EDIT #1 above for an example.

Comment: This seems like a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem in disguise. What DB are you using?

Comment: Regarding your points 1 and 2, these might be of interest: [SQLAlchemy-Continuum](https://github.com/kvesteri/sqlalchemy-continuum), and the examples [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#versioning-objects).

Comment: Both of those are very interesting. The versioning seems to accomodate function, but also seems a bit overkill for my use. Ill have to explore it more. Thanks.